# how to get image from document directry to uiview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i am saving image on document directry like this
in document directry the image is asaving like saveimage0.png,saveimage1.png...etc like this image is enter in document i create int variable for increment count with image num=0;
insert is working proper but how to get multiple image from document folder in loadimage menthod is right or wrong i want tkae image and save in array and display on view

```
int num=0;
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{


    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView.image = image;
        UIImage *image1 =imageView.image;
        NSData *myData = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) retain];
        imagedata = myData;


        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveimage%d.png",num]];
        num += 1; // for next t
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

and i am fetching image from document directry same as

```
int value;
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    // NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
   //[NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"savedImage-",@"%@-%d.png", value]];

    value += 1;

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return image;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is within your question.

You are saving image using:

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveimage%d.png",num]];
```

The format is : **saveimage0.png**

And you are retrieving like:

```
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"savedImage-",@"%@-%d.png", value]];
```

The format is: `savedImage-aValue-aValue.png`.

Change it to:

```
 NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"savedimage%d.png", value]];
```

Comment: hi it crash bec i am calling this load method from here for each time when new photo will add     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [imagesArray addObject:[self loadImage]];
   
}

Comment: @Rocky: is there anything on the console ?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint, and check where it is crashing. Also check the returned image is nil or not ? I think the image is nil that's why it is crashing

Comment: it getting here bad exc in this method - (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"savedImage-",@"%@-%d.png", value]];
    value += 1;
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return images;// here it crash on return TIME
}

Comment: NO I GETTING IMAGE THIS PATH /Users/pradeepyadav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6ACAF896-4857-4AC7-AC1A-49D8DDEA2F4F/Documents/savedImage0.png BUT ON RETURN TIME IT CRASH

Comment: before returning just put this line, NSLog(@"Image : %@",image); let me know what is the output

Comment: THE IMAGE IS GETTING NULL VALUE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22023/discussion-between-midhun-mp-and-rocky)

Comment: Please come to chat by clicking above link